# jquery .click function not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, click

I have the following HTML and Javascript code. I am trying to make a search suggestion system. The list-items in the unordered-list 'search_suggest' are retrieved dynamically using ajax as the user types in the input box 'site_search' and inserted.

```
<form name="search_site_form" method="get" action="search.php">
        <input id="site_search" name="q" class="search_input input" autocomplete="off" value="Search the site" type="text"/>

    <ul id="search_suggest">
    </ul>
    <input value=" " type="submit" class="search_submit"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        $("ul#search_suggest>li").click(function(){ 
        alert('123');
    });
    //-->
    </script>
</form>
```

Clicking on the list items in search_suggest however is not triggering the click function. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind the click event to the list items *after* they have been added to the page.

Before any list items get added to the page, the expression `$("ul#search_suggest>li")` finds nothing, so no elements get bound to the click event.

You need to use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) that will:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future

Like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $("ul#search_suggest>li").live('click', function(){ 
    alert('123');
});
//-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running once, binding the onclick action to non-existent `<li>` elements. You will need to build into your AJAX script something that will add the onclick to each `<li>` element as they are added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

use the [jQuery.live();](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        $("ul#search_suggest>li").live('click', function(){ 
        alert('123');
    });
    //-->
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("ul#search_suggest+input").click(function(){ 
        alert('123');
    });
```

Here the input tag is the next sibling of an ul with id earch_suggest
`+` is the [`jQuery Next Sibling Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

The selector "ul#search_suggest>li" means find the li which is the child of the ul with id search suggest.
`>` is the [`jQuery Child Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Add empty li or li with values into  and test it like this
`<ul id="search_suggest">
 <li></li>
</ul>`